# How Can I Use Selenium in Excel Without SeleniumBasic?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I created a tool on the job using Excel, VBA and SeleniumBasic to drive Chrome or Edge to go to a company web page and enter some data.  The tool works well, but when I requested that it be distributed to a wider audience, I was told that although Selenium is approved for use on company networks, SeleniumBasic is not.

So my question is, is it possible/easy to **drive Selenium directly with VBA** and avoid having to use SeleniumBasic?  The approval process for FOSS is not easy and would take too long, so I think I have to find a workaround.

Comment: SeleniumBasic is what lets you use Selenium from VBA: you'd have to re-invent it if you can't use it as-is.

Comment: Are you able to build this as a C# or Visual Basic application?

Comment: Greg Burghardt - I could probably move this into Visual Studio as a VB app, but in the end I need to create an Excel add-in, which is far easier to distribute than a stand-alone app.

Comment: An alternative is to use libEdge, Microsoft's Chrome-based browser with interface to VBA, C++ and C#. Samples included: https://github.com/peakpeak-github/libEdge